# How to sum only numbers in array with different value types with reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, sum, reduce

I need sum only numbers of this array with `reduce` but I don’t know how.

This is my code and my attempt:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,6,true,"Dio Brando", false,10,"yare yare"];

let sum = arr.reduce((a.b)=> typeOf.a =="number" && typeOf.b =="number"? a+b :false)
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: You need to learn basic Javascript syntax before worrying about high-level operations like this.

Answer (score 7):

You need to make the following changes:

- (a.b) should be (a, b), it's function with parameters
- there's no such thing as "typeOf.a", it should be "typeof a"

I've rewritten with some more helpful variable names to explain what's going on in the reduce.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,6,true,"Dio Brando", false,10,"yare yare"];

const sum = arr.reduce( (sumSoFar, nextValue) => {
   if ( typeof nextValue === "number" && isFinite(nextValue) ) {
      return sumSoFar + nextValue;
   }
   //skip otherwise
   return sumSoFar;
}, 0); //sum starting from zero
 
 console.log(sum);
```

Comment: I’m not sure about that `isFinite`. Why is that check necessary?

Comment: Prevents summing stuff like NaN (Not a Number). Just a precaution really!

Comment: But then I would’ve used `!isNaN` instead. IMO it should be possible to get `Infinity` as the sum if `Infinity` occurs in the array.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough - depends on the use case I guess!

Answer (score 3):

You’ve got some syntax errors along with logical errors.

- There is no `typeOf`, it’s `typeof` which takes an operand, not a property: `typeof a`.
- Arguments are separated with commas, not dots: `(a, b) =>`…

It’ll be easier if you provide a starting value (`0`), then you only need to check the type of the second argument. I’ll also recommend giving the arguments more intuitive names than single letter `a`s and `b`s.

```
arr.reduce((sum, value) => (typeof value == "number" ? sum + value : sum), 0);
```

You need to return the *aggregate* value (`sum`, since it’s a sum) for the next iteration. If you return `false`, you lose the entire summation.

Comment: You could just short circuit parseFloat `let res = arr.reduce((s, v) => (parseFloat(v) || 0) + s, 0);
`

Comment: thanks, is my first question here..and well, thanks for you time , your tip of index 0 is so useful :D

Answer (score 1):

ok this will do it you can beautify if statement if you want:

```
let sum = arr.reduce((prevVal, currVal, index)=> {
 if (typeof prevVal =="number" && typeof currVal =="number"){
  return currVal+prevVal;
 } else {
   return prevVal;
}
});
```